# Shopify 'View all' button implementation

Tags: javascript, jquery, shopify

Shopify has a max display limit of 50 products per page.

To get around this limitation I've made a jquery code snippet. The script grabs the url from each pagination link, and performs an ajax load - adding the result to the main content area.

It worked perfectly for me - but not for my friend. He was missing a page each time. So I thought it may be an async issue with his connection being slower than mine. So I rewrote the script a few times to be more explicit. But it still didn't work for him.

After much trouble shooting, it appears that if logged in as admin - everything works. If not logged in, then the middle page fails to load.

Here is my most recent code:

```
{% if template contains 'collection' %}
 <script>

$(document).ready(function() {

$('#viewFewerProducts').hide();


// when viewAllProducts is clicked
$("#viewAllProducts").click( function (e) {
e.preventDefault();
$("#viewAllProducts , #paginationMagic").hide(); // hide pagination buttons
// and clear out collectionThumbs - but add the ViewAllRow back in.
$("#collectionThumbs").empty().html('<div class="row" id="viewAllRow"></div>');

// see how many pagination links there are. Add 1 because of index 0
var numberOfPages = $('#paginateNumbers .item').length + 1
var path = window.location.pathname;
var pageURL;


// this bit adapted from blog post... but cant remember url
for (var i=1;i<numberOfPages;i++) { 
    $.ajax(
    {
        type: 'GET',
        url:  pageURL = path + "?page=" + i, // build pagination page url
        ajaxI: i, // Capture the current value of 'i'.
        success: function(data)
    {
        i = this.ajaxI; // Reinstate the correct value for 'i'.
    $(data).find('#collectionThumbs').each(function()
    {
      // Read data... and stick it in the page
     var importedCollection = $(data).find("#collectionThumbs a").unwrap();
     importedCollection.appendTo("#viewAllRow");
    });
    },
        error: function(data)
    {
    // Handle errors here.
    }
    });
}
///

    $("#viewFewerProducts").show();

});

// reload the window
$("#viewFewerProducts").click( function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#viewFewerProducts").text('loading...').removeAttr('id');
    location.reload();
});


});

</script>
{% endif %}
```

and I've written it several other different ways. It just doesn't work if not logged in? I've checked  - and dont get any errors in the console either.

So my question is - does anyone know why it would work if logged in, but not if not logged in to admin? Its really bizzarre - as this is not running on any admin pages.

Edit:

```
{% if template contains 'collection' %}
 <script>

$(document).ready(function() {

$('#viewFewerProducts').hide();



$("#viewAllProducts").click( function (e) {
e.preventDefault();
    $("#viewAllProducts , #paginationMagic").hide();


    var numberOfPages = $('#paginateNumbers .item').length + 1
    var path = window.location.pathname;
    // console.log(path);
    var pageURL;

    //

    for (var i=1;i<numberOfPages;i++) {
    // console.log(i + 'a')
    $.ajax(
    {
    type: 'GET',
    url:  pageURL = path + "?page=" + i,
    beforeSend: function() {
    $("#collectionThumbs").empty();
    },
    ajaxI: i, // Capture the current value of 'i'.
    success: function(data)
    {
    i = this.ajaxI; // Reinstate the correct value for 'i'.

        $(data).find('#collectionThumbs').each(function() {
        // Read data from XML...
         $('<div class="row" id="viewAllRow' + i + '"></div>').appendTo("#collectionThumbs");
         var importedCollection = $(data).find("#collectionThumbs a").unwrap(); 
          importedCollection.appendTo("#viewAllRow" + i );

        // alert("now showing " +  ($("#viewAllRow" + i + " a").length)  + " products" );
        });

        var numberOfRows = $('#collectionThumbs .row').length + 1
        var viewAllRowItem = []

        for (var x=1;x<numberOfRows;x++) {
            //put each row into a variable
             viewAllRowItem[x] = $("#viewAllRow" + x ).clone();
             $("#viewAllRow" + x ).remove();
             // console.log(viewAllRowItem[x])
        }

        for (var x=1;x<numberOfRows;x++) {
                $(viewAllRowItem[x]).appendTo('#collectionThumbs');
        }

    },
    dataType: "html",
    error: function(data)
    {
    // Handle errors here.
    }
    });




}



$("#viewFewerProducts").show();


});


$("#viewFewerProducts").click( function (e) {
e.preventDefault();
$("#viewFewerProducts").text('loading...').removeAttr('id');
location.reload();

});

});

</script>
{% endif %}
```

The above code seems to work - not sure why... was a process of elimination. I did have to add a bit of code to reorder the elements once loaded (as some ajax responses came back more quickly than others - and appeared on the page in the wrong order).

Comment: Since you can paginate any collection using Liquid, why would you go with this approach instead of just paginating? If you want to show off 100 products per page, and you have 1000 products, you'll get 10 pages to work with, and no XHR nonsense to deal with.

Comment: Hi David, I used liquid for the pagination - the ajax call hits those pagination links to know which page to pull the html from... Has Shopify has lifted its api limit?

Comment: Have made an edit / update. How do I mark it solved?

Comment: have you checked if you are getting the data from Ajax request with different login ?

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('[js-load-more]').on('click', function(){
  var $this = $(this),totalPages = parseInt($('[data-total-pages]').val()),currentPage = parseInt($('[data-current-page]').val());
  $this.attr('disabled', true);
  $this.find('[load-more-text]').addClass('hide');
  $this.find('[loader]').removeClass('hide');
  currentPage = currentPage+1;
  var nextUrl = $('[data-next-url]').val().replace(/page=[0-9]+/,'page='+currentPage);
  $('[data-current-page]').val(currentPage);
  $.ajax({
    url: nextUrl,
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: 'html',
    success: function(responseHTML){
      $('.grid--view-items').append($(responseHTML).find('.grid--view-items').html());
    },
    complete: function() {
      if(currentPage >= totalPages) {
        $this.remove();
      }
      else {
        $this.attr('disabled', false);
        $this.find('[load-more-text]').removeClass('hide');
        $this.find('[loader]').addClass('hide');
      }
    }
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <input type="hidden" value="{{ paginate.next.url }}" data-next-url>
        <input type="hidden" value="{{ paginate.pages }}" data-total-pages>
        <input type="hidden" value="{{ paginate.current_page  }}" data-current-page>
        <div class="load-more_wrap">
          <button class="btn" js-load-more>
            <span load-more-text>Load more</span>
            <span class="hide" loader></span>
          </button>
        </div>
```